# onClick Switching Classes issue

Tags: jquery

What i have is `<div#graphicsCloseBox>` nested inside `<div#catbox>`.
It's supposed to be when you click , the class changes back.
I cannot use toggleClass because there is a form input inside box, so clicking the form messes things up.

```
 $('#catbox').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('cat');
        $(this).addClass('cat2');
});
$('#graphicsCloseBox').click(function() {
    $('#catbox').removeClass('cat2');
    $('#catbox').addClass('cat');
});
```

if you want an example check http://codepen.io/rtro92/pen/mihlu
but this is pretty much straightforward.
I know my problem is in the 2nd function, I just can't target the #catbox.
Thanks!

Comment: provide some html please

Comment: to avoid the length, you could just use `.toggleClass('cat2 cat')`

Comment: i can't use toggle because it has form input in it. clicking the the input field would activate the toggle then, so i believe i have to use add/removeclass

Comment: Also you can add a .click event to your form inputs, ( .click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation() }); to stop the events from bubbling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is probably [event propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Events) (a.k.a. "bubbling"), which is the functionality that the events in one DOM element "bubbles" to all its parents, unless the event is specifically told not to do so.

In other words, when someone clicks the `<div#graphicsCloseBox>`, the classes are correctly added and removed as you specified. Then directly after, the `click` event on `<div#catbox>` is triggered, which - since it resets the classes - undoes the effect of the click on the inner `<div>`.

To fix it, use [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$('#graphicsCloseBox').click(function(evt) {
    // your other stuff
    evt.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

It should work without `return false` at the end, but since most browsers can use a "falsy" return value to prevent bubbling, I usually tuck it on there anyway.

Comment: Sigh... And of course, when you take the time to find some links, verify in the example that it actually solves the problems etc, a handful of other people already posted the same answer :P

Comment: thanks, yours is the best. putting it english makes sense, I understand what it means. Appreciated.

Comment: +1 For the effort. As soon as I saw this I knew there was no point in editing mine. 1st place in the last curve and to the finish line, well played sir.

Answer (score 6):

You're click event is bubbling up to the outer DIV.

Use `.stopPropagation()`

```
$('#catbox').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('cat');
        $(this).addClass('cat2');
});
$('#graphicsCloseBox').click(function(event) {
    $('#catbox').removeClass('cat2');
    $('#catbox').addClass('cat');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this change:

```
$('#graphicsCloseBox').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();  //<---This stops it from bubbling up, toggle now works.
    $('#catbox').removeClass('cat2');
    $('#catbox').addClass('cat');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dealing with event bubbling - Clicking #graphicsCloseBox also triggers the click actions on #catbox.  Try stopping the event from bubbling up.

```
$('#graphicsCloseBox').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#catbox').removeClass('cat2');
    $('#catbox').addClass('cat');
});
```